# Turn off Scala lint warnings at a less-than-global scope?

Tags: scala, lint

I'd like to be able to turn off a particular compiler warning, but only for a single file in my project.  Is this possible?

The context is that I have a single source file that makes calls to an external macro library that produces adapted-arg warnings.  I found that I can eliminate these warnings by changing my `build.sbt` file:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Xlint:-adapted-args,_" /*, ... */)
```

However, this turns off the warning globally, and I only want it off for the single file that raises them.

I haven't had any luck searching for any of the following possible solutions I thought might exist:

- Specifying separate compilation options for different files in my project in my `build.sbt` file
- Providing some pragma-like comment in my source file to change the warnings generated by the compiler, similar to the special `scalastyle:on/off` comments recognized by Scalastyle
- Some annotation for smaller regions of code, like `@unchecked`

So, is there any way to have different linting options in effect for different files, or even for limited regions of code?

Comment: you could specify a submodule in your project and compile that file - with its dependencies - there. Than add the submodule as a dependency to the main module. It seems like an overkill, but at least you could specify different options on each submodule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expectation was that folks would write a custom `Reporter` that would filter out undesirable warnings.

It's easy to write one that filters by file name, perhaps given a whitelist.

The error/warn API supplies the textual `Position`. It would also be easy to parse the `position.lineContent` for a magic comment token like `IGNORE` or `SUPPRESS`, which is not as convenient as a `SuppressWarnings` annotation but is easy to implement.

The compiler asks the reporter if there were errors.

The custom reporter is specified with `-Xreporter myclass`, or it wouldn't surprise me if someone has written an sbt plugin.

Comment: I'm using scalac 2.11.6, and `-Xreporter` is not a recognized option.

Comment: In that unfortunate case, I would write a macro that rewrites the call that incurs the warning. `rewrite(f())` where `f()` expands to the unadapted invocation `g(1,2,3)` should expand to `g(Tuple3(1,2,3))`. There was an issue about whether warnings are emitted for unexpanded macro invocations, but I don't know offhand if that was fixed.